# Conditional std::future and std::async

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

I need to do conditional behavior.

```
std::future<int> f = pointer ? std::async(&Class::method, ptr) : 0;

// ... Some code

x = f.get();
```

So I would like to assign to x result async result of `ptr->method()` call or 0 if `ptr` is a `nullptr`.

Is the code above ok? Can I do anything like that (assign 'int' to 'std::futture'? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) have no conversion [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/future) so your code is not valid (as you would have noticed if you actually tried to compile the code).

What you can do is use a default-constructed future, and then check if it's [valid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/valid) before you use the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can load a value into the future without using a thread like this:

```
std::future<int> f;

if ( pointer )
    f = std::async(&Class::method, ptr);
else
{
    std::promise<int> p;
    p.set_value(0);
    f = p.get_future();
}

// ... Some code
x = f.get();
```

But a simpler way to achieve the same goal would be:

```
std::future<int> f;

if ( pointer )
    f = std::async(&Class::method, ptr);

// ... Some code
x = f.valid() ? f.get() : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may return also a `std::future` for your other case (using different policy):

```
std::future<int> f = pointer
    ? std::async(&Class::method, ptr)
    : std::async(std::launch::deferred, [](){ return 0;});
```